# Почему в 1 месте спавняться 2 блока?

Tags: lua, roblox

В этой функции мы считаем сколько всего заспавнилось блоков

```
function countOre()
      _G.OreSpawned = 0
      for i, s in pairs(OreSpawnTable) do
        if s:FindFirstChild('Wood') or s:FindFirstChild('Stone') then
          _G.OreSpawned += 1
        end
      end
      print(_G.OreSpawned)
      return _G.OreSpawned
    end
```

Это бесконечный цикл на спавн блоков. Где идёт проверка if AmountOres < maxOres then (Если количество заспавленых блоков < Максимального количества, то цикл не будет ничего спавнить)

```
function OresSpawner()
  while true do
    
    local AmountOres = countOre()
    
    if AmountOres < maxOres then
      local RandomOre = Ores[math.random(1, #Ores)]
      local OreClone = RandomOre:Clone()

      local RandomSpawn
      
      repeat
        RandomSpawn = OreSpawnTable[math.random(1, #OreSpawnTable)]
      until not RandomSpawn:FindFirstChild('Stone') or not RandomSpawn:FindFirstChild('Wood')

      OreClone.Parent = RandomSpawn
      OreClone.CFrame = RandomSpawn.CFrame + Vector3.new(0,3,0)
    end
    
    wait(2)
  end
end
```

Проблема заключается в том что 2 блока могут заспавниться в 1 месте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО если поменять в коде то что спавнить нужно только Stone, получиться вот такой код:

```
function countOre()
  _G.OreSpawned = 0
  for i, s in pairs(OreSpawnTable) do
    if s:FindFirstChild('Wood') or s:FindFirstChild('Stone') then
      _G.OreSpawned += 1
    end
  end
  print(_G.OreSpawned)
  return _G.OreSpawned
end

function OresSpawner()
  while true do
    
    local AmountOres = countOre()
    
    if AmountOres < maxOres then
      local RandomOre = Ores[1]
      local OreClone = RandomOre:Clone()

      local RandomSpawn
      
      repeat
        RandomSpawn = OreSpawnTable[math.random(1, #OreSpawnTable)]
      until not RandomSpawn:FindFirstChild('Stone')

      OreClone.Parent = RandomSpawn
      OreClone.CFrame = RandomSpawn.CFrame + Vector3.new(0,3,0)
    end
    
    wait(2)
  end
end
```

То в итоге всё хорошо работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]